# Odd behavior with iAd in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios5, iad

I have source code that implemented an iAD banner, and did so successfully on all versions of iOS 4. However, since upgrading my test device to iOS 5 I noticed that there were never any test ads, despite test ads being available and visible on the simulator. Originally I thought that this was due to Apple not serving ads, or test ads, to iOS 5 devices since iOS 5 wasn't released yet.

With the release of iOS 5 for all devices previously I've noticed that this problem is now prevalent on other devices that were upgraded to iOS 5. I'm following the samples that Apple has posted in my own code. And even stranger, debugging the samples in the iAdSuite sample projects I find that those crash.

Has anyone else seen this behavior?

Comment: Just noticed that on a brand new iPhone 4S I can see actual ads through iAd, so I'm actually really confused now.

Answer (score 0):

No crash but "random" test banners yes! Keep in mind that Apple claim on Apple dev forum they not deliver ads to developer anymore (so if you debug your app on your iPhone you always get test banners). I say "claim" 'cause lots of developer report lots of different behaviors, so nothing is really sure thing. I suggest you to monitor your iAD reports (request, fill rate and so on) and see if there are big differences: in this case try asking on iAD section of Apple dev forum...

Comment: To further my confusion, it appears as though only on iOS 5 my app (TZ-Viewer) is not seeing any ad banners from iAd. Nothing has changed in my code, yet I'm seeing almost no requests for ads. This has to be incorrect because I know that I've tried to find an ad the past few days and haven't seen one (and I've definitely tried looking at views that access my app's adBanner more times than ITC says all instances of my app has).

I don't think I've missed anything in the iOS 5 release notes but has iAd implementation changed? According to the iAdSuite, it hasn't.

Comment: if you think something gone wrong probably is better to contact Apple's people from the iTunesconnect site. As I said, some days you can get odd results, but in example my apps are getting good fill rates in these days (in Italian iAD circuit)

Comment: Thanks. I've brought this up with them so now I'm just waiting to hear back. Good to hear that iAds are getting impressions in Italy!!! :)